# Define data structures from configuration files

Tags: c

I'm not new to C programming but I havn't got the chance to touch it for a lot of time.

I'd like your advice on a way to define data structures (struct) which are defined in a configuration file.  At the moment, I haven't defined the structure for the configuration file but I'm guessing it will be something like ini file.

Basically I'm working on Windows and Linux so I'd love an answer for both OS.

Comment: Don't write it yourself. There are lots of such stuff out there. One example could be JSON formatted configuration files. Then you can find code on the net that does all the parsing for you.

Comment: Are you planning a precompiler which converts the configuration file into structure definitions, or a run-time process?  The latter will be messier.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ... and the former can also handle the latter (edit: by *handle*, I mean a wrapper can be built).

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like your advice on a way to define data structures (struct) which are defined in a configuration file

The simplest method, by far, would be to use header (`.h`) files as your configuration files. You could include them into your project like so:

```
#include CONFIG_FILE
```

... and introduce them during compilation like so:

```
cc -D'CONFIG_FILE="path/to/config.h"' path/to/source/files.c
```

If you wrap all of your config values into function-like-macros from the very start, this should be nice and flexible; you shouldn't have a problem generating clean `struct`s from your INI files.

> I'm guessing it will be something like ini file

I should point out that in the world of C, *define* has a *very strict* meaning, and to *define data structures (struct)* can only be done in C source files (or header files, which are later included into source files).

Suit yourself! My recommendation would give you an interface that allows you to put the lexing/parsing on hold until a (much) later point in time (i.e. when you have the time to write a full-fledged INI-to-C-header compiler, because that's what you're asking about), and give you an interface with which to *fill in the blanks*, so to say.

Comment: I afraid he asks about the run time, not the compile time

Comment: @PeterJ_01 As I already stated, *define* has a *very strict* meaning. That meaning can be found [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p5). Examples can be found [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.1p4), [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p26), **[here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p28)** and **[throughout the entire section entitled "external object definitions"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2)**, among other places. According to the standard, *definition* is not a process that occurs in the execution environment.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Such a module should be compartmentalised so that, like the rest of the program, it can be tested in isolation, and like the configuration module, the rest of the program can be tested without it.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I'm not talking about `#define`, either; that's not mentioned in any of the sections I cited. Your comments are drifting further and further away from relevance, and I find your demanding tone to be aggressive. Please refer to the section entitled "When should I comment?" of the [StackOverflow comment privileges help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you're unwilling to consider my responses, then your criticism is most likely non-constructive.